# Predefined custom view in custom view group do not shows on screen

Tags: android

First, I created custom view which extends from View. For now I want to create group view with predefind child. I tried with this code, but my view did not show:

```
public class CustomGroupView extends ViewGroup {

    public CustomGroupView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        addView(new CustomView(context, attrs));
    }


    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean hasFocus, int i, int i2, int i3, int i4) {

    }
}




<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <com.sample.viewGroup.CustomGroupView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />



</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change com.sample.viewGroup.CustomViewGroup

to

com.sample.viewGroup.CustomGroupView

Comment: Post your CustomViewGroup xml ?

Answer (score 0):

I added this, and it works.

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {

  child.layout(right, top, left, bottom);

}
```